# Telnet output delays

Tags: telnet, lag, suse

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 0
```

On server running legacy software with text GUI (perl/c).

When connected via ssh - all is ok. When connected via telnet - both, screen redraws and sending pressed keys to server work with visible delays.

Why? And how to fix?

**UPD**
If I connect to host via ssh, and after that run `telnet localhost` - delays does not occurs.

Comment: Does "don't use telnet" qualify as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Unfortunately no

Comment: Well then; does connecting to localhost within an otherwise responsive session incur the same delays as a (presumably) remote telnet connection?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling update question